# Warning with Beamer in French

Tags: beamer, warnings, french

Whenever I create a presentation document with Beamer in French, the following warning comes up on the `\begin{document}` command:

```
Package frenchb.ldf Warning: Setting StandardEnumerateEnv=true for
(frenchb.ldf)                compatibility with enumerate package,
(frenchb.ldf)                 on input line 7.
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\frame{A}
\end{document}
```

What does this warning mean and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: The `silence` package can turn off warnings that we know are innocuous.

Comment: Did you use `frenchb.ldf 2014/06/21 v3.1a`?

Comment: I don't know, I'm using writeLaTeX which in turn uses TeX Live 2013. https://www.writelatex.com/help/30-what-packages-do-you-support

Comment: @Neptilo Add `\listfiles` to your code, compile it, download your entire directory as a ZIP (with output files), then look into the .log file: `writeLatex` uses `frenchb.ldf 2013/12/30 v2.6g`. There is no warning with recent versions of `frenchb`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Very good. I hope writeLaTeX will update their packages soon. In the meantime I used `silence`. I wish I could accept one of the comments above as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the meaning I'd like to quote the documentation http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb.pdf

> StandardEnumerateEnv=true (false*) ; starting with version 2.6 frenchb re- defines the enumerate and description environments to make left margins match those of the French version of itemize lists. Setting this option to false reverts to the standard definition of enumerate and description.

---

**EDIT February 2018:**

With an up-to-date texlive2017 this warning no longer appears. In case you get the warning, try to update your tex distribution.

Comment: Yes, I stumbled upon this. It explains what the effects of the compiler's behavior will be (in this case, it will use the newer definition of enumerate), but not why there was a warning in the first place, nor how to get rid of it.